# Automatic class generator Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to create some class generator with dependencies of user action. For example,

1. every time I create a new `CoreData Entity` class I want to create a category class for it with some content already.
2. Every time i create a sublass of existing class i want some method to be appear in `.m` file already (like `drawInRect:` when you create a new `UIView` sublass.

Example 
(.h)

```
@interface MyFavouriteClassSubclass : MyFavouriteClass
```

(.m):

```
@implementation MyFavouriteClassSubclass

-(void)someMethodInMyParentClass {
  [super someMethodInMyParentClass];
}
```

Can that be done?

I was think about some shell script to achive that, but the problem with it, that I already need to have a file, and it can run as a cronjob. I don't think is a good aproach for that.

Comment: Hi. For the coredata see [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)

Answer (score 0):

I see two obvious potential routes. You mentioned one already, a script, which need not be a shell script. The script could be as follows, logically:

- Given input of an `xcodeproj` file,
- For each class referenced that has the string `****: NSManagedObject`,

  - Get the file name containing the class `Placeholder.h`,`Placeholder.m`
  - Check to see if there is some file `Placeholder+****.h`,`Placeholder+****.m`
  - If there is not, create a new file named `Placeholder+extensions.h`,`Placeholder+extensions.m` in some default location, and add it to some default group

Writing a shell script is not my cup of tea because I don't like the syntax but it is favored because there is already a hook for it to run on build.

You could adapt one of the many new task runners out there (say `gulp` with `gulp-watch`) for the purpose of watching for changes to some specific directory or directories and then calling a script of choice.

Another way to implement would be to write your own XCode plugin. There is a plugin template https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template out there but I've personally had enough issues with the XCode plugin system to make me not want to use it.

**Edit**

In any case, check this out: https://github.com/appsquickly/XcodeEditor

It doesn't have 100% of what you need but it ain't a bad start.